# Нужна ли запятая перед вторым предлогом?

Tags: пунктуация

Если возможно, перенесите встречу на среду на 16.00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимости в запятой нет (день и время), но она может и стоять по авторскому хотению — как уточнение на когда и именно когда.

Час записывается так:

**16:00**